# Node with the lowest number of path ending

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

There is a problem for the Algorithms course.

> You need to create a company. There are n candidates for employees in
> your company, and you should select as many employees as possible.
> However, there are several limitations. First, the structure of the
> company must be strictly hierarchical: the company must have a single
> director, the director has several (possibly 0) direct subordinates,
> each of them has several (perhaps 0) direct subordinates, etc.
> Employee A is called the boss of employee B if B is a direct
> subordinate of A or B is a direct subordinate of A and so on.
> Employees occasionally play some 1vs1 games. If employee A lost to
> employee B, A can never be a boss of B. Here transitivity also holds.
> If A lost to B and B lost to C, A can never be a boss of C and so on.
> As input, you get n, a number of games, and the result of each game
> (who lost to who). As output, you should obtain the maximum size of
> the company.

Here's what I got.
We can represent the game results as a directed graph with nodes representing employees. There is an edge (A, B) if B lost to A. Now, if for each node we find a number of nodes that cannot reach this node, then the maximum of these values will be the answer to the problem.

I tried to do it by using DFS on each node, but this takes too long. Thus, there must be some solution with better asymptotic complexity. Can you give me any ideas? I attach my code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>


class Graph {
    uint16_t number_of_vertices_;
    std::vector<std::vector<uint16_t>> adjacent_;
    void DFSUtil(uint16_t vertex);
public:
    std::vector<uint16_t> fooled_by_;

    explicit Graph(uint16_t number_of_vertices);

    void AddEdge(uint16_t first_vertex, uint16_t second_vertex) {
        adjacent_[first_vertex].push_back(second_vertex);
    }

    void FindTransitiveClosure();

    uint16_t FindMaxSizeOfCompany();
};


Graph::Graph(uint16_t number_of_vertices) {
    number_of_vertices_ = number_of_vertices;

    std::vector<std::vector<uint16_t>> adjacent(number_of_vertices);
    adjacent_ = adjacent;

    std::vector<uint16_t> fooled_by(number_of_vertices, number_of_vertices);
    fooled_by_ = fooled_by;
}


void Graph::DFSUtil(uint16_t vertex) {

    std::vector<bool> visited(number_of_vertices_, false);
    std::stack<uint16_t> stack;

    stack.push(vertex);
    visited[vertex] = true;

    uint16_t current_vertex;
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        current_vertex = stack.top();
        stack.pop();


        for (size_t i =0; i < adjacent_[current_vertex].size(); ++i) {
            if (!visited[adjacent_[current_vertex][i]]) {
                visited[adjacent_[current_vertex][i]] = true;
                --fooled_by_[adjacent_[current_vertex][i]];
                stack.push(adjacent_[current_vertex][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}


void Graph::FindTransitiveClosure() {
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < number_of_vertices_; ++i) {
        DFSUtil(i);
    }
}


uint16_t Graph::FindMaxSizeOfCompany() {
    uint16_t max_sum = 0;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < number_of_vertices_; ++i) {
        if (max_sum < fooled_by_[i]) {
            max_sum = fooled_by_[i];
        }
    }

    return max_sum;
}


void ReadGraph(uint16_t number_of_edges, Graph &fool) {

    uint16_t first_vertex, second_vertex, won;
    for (uint16_t counter = 0; counter < number_of_edges; ++counter) {
        std::cin >> first_vertex >> second_vertex >> won;
        if (won == 1) {
            fool.AddEdge(first_vertex - 1, second_vertex - 1);
        }
        if (won == 2) {
            fool.AddEdge(second_vertex - 1, first_vertex - 1);
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);

    uint16_t number_of_vertices, number_of_edges;
    std::cin >> number_of_vertices >> number_of_edges;

    Graph fool(number_of_vertices);
    ReadGraph(number_of_edges, fool);

    fool.FindTransitiveClosure();

    std::cout << fool.FindMaxSizeOfCompany();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I was able to meet the time limit. I used Tarjan’s Algorithm to find strongly connected components. Then only used DFS for one node from each SCC.

Comment: Assuming you've got the transitive closure of the graph, why isn't the solution just the person with the fewest losses as the director, with all the people that she hasn't lost to as her subordinates?

Comment: @PaulHankin I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. What you proposed is indeed a solution if by "lost" you mean both directly and indirectly.

Comment: What's the asymptotic complexity of your solution? What is even the input data that takes too long? Do you have test cases that give correct results?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I do DFS for each node. If we assume that number of nodes (n) is roughly equal to the number of edges, then complexity is O(n^2), O(n^3) if graph is dense. Input is bounded by 50000 nodes and 50000 edges. This solution passes multiple test, but exceeds time limit on one of the later tests. I cannot see the input of this test, but I assume that it has large n (when I computed transitive closure, it exceeded memory limit).